# Question on Eigen values

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a square matrix and $A^*$ be its adjoint, show that the eigenvalues of matrices $AA^*$ and $A^*A$ are real. Further show that $\operatorname {trace}(AA^*)=\operatorname {trace}(A^*A)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\lambda \in \mathbb C$ be an eigenvalue of $A^*A$ and $x \in \mathbb C^n$ a corresponding eigenvector. Then 
$$ \lambda(x,x) = (\lambda x,x) = (A^*Ax,x) = (x,A^*Ax) = (x,\lambda x) = \bar\lambda(x,x)$$
Dividing by $(x,x) \ne 0$ gives $\lambda = \bar \lambda$, hence $\lambda \in \mathbb R$. The same proof works for $AA^*$.

The fact about the trace follows from a more general fact, namely: If $A \in {\rm Mat}(n,k)$ and $B\in {\rm Mat}(k,n)$ are matrices over some field $K$ then $\def\tr{\mathop{\rm trace}}\tr(AB) = \tr(BA)$. This can be seen as follows:
\begin{align*}
  \tr(AB) &= \sum_{i=1}^n (AB)_{ii}\\
          &= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^k A_{ij}B_{ji}\\
          &= \sum_{j=1}^k \sum_{i=1}^n B_{ji}A_{ij}\\
          &= \sum_{j=1}^k (BA)_{jj}\\
          &= \tr(BA).
\end{align*}

Comment: forgive my ignorance. What does λ(x,x) stand for ? I am not able follow the first part is there any other method?

Comment: $(\cdot, \cdot)$ denotes the inner product, so $\lambda(x,x)$ is $\lambda$ multiplied with the norm-square of $x$.

Comment: (λx,x)=(A∗Ax,x) How is this possible λ is a scalar while A∗A is matrix. Please explain the rationale behind this step.

Comment: @Swami $x$ is an eigenvector for $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, hence $A^*Ax = \lambda x$.

Comment: If x is an eigenvector for A with eigenvalue λ, then we should have Ax = λx then how did we get A∗Ax=λx ?

Comment: I choose $\lambda$ to be an eigenvalue for $A^*A$, not for $A$. $\lambda$ and $x$ are such that $(A^*A)x = \lambda x$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification please explain the last step (x,λx)=λ¯(x,x).

Comment: The inner product is semi-linear in its second component.

Comment: (A∗Ax,x)=(x,A∗Ax) In this I think one should be conjugate of the other i.e. LHS = conjugate(RHS)

Comment: No, we do not use the $(x,y) = \overline{(y,x)}$ property of the product, but the definition of the adjoint (two times): $$(A^*Ax,x) = (Ax,Ax) = (x,A^*Ax)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $(\lambda,x)$ ne an eigenpair of $A^*A$, wlog we may suppose $\|x\|_2 = 1$, so that then
$$\lambda = \lambda \|x\|^2_2 = <\lambda x,x> = <A^*Ax,x> = <Ax,Ax> = \|Ax\|_2^2 \in \mathbb{R},$$
so $\lambda$ must be real. For the same reason every eigenvalue of $AA^*$ are reals. For the trace, see its properties [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29#Trace_of_a_product).

**Shorter proof:**
$(AA^*)=A^{**}A^* = AA^*$ and $(A^*A)^* = A^*A$, thus these are self adjoint operators and have therefore only real eigenvalues.

Comment: "thus these are self adjoint operators and have therefore only positive eigenvalues." - Surely you mean real?

Comment: @Sten Yes obviously, this is a typo... thanks!